# I need to put my table data into ListView (MVVM)

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Database connection and binding context are okay. Data can insert into a table without a problem. I need to add last of my table data row to a list view

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}" 
          verticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Catagoryview}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Expense}"/>

                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

this is my XAML file. I create every property for in binding here. with backing fields.

in my ViewModel

```
private void add()
{
    database = new Database();
    var expensedata = database.GetExpenses(id);

    if (expensedata != null)
    {
        Catagoryview = expensedata.Catagory;
        Date= expensedata.Date;
        Expense = expensedata.Expense; 
    }
}
```

I know this code is not perfect. I really need to get the last 10 rows of my data into a list view.

also, here my get expenses method I used

```
public AddExpenses GetExpenses(int expense)
{
    return Conn.Table<AddExpenses>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == expense);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you've rolled back my changes? I think that I did not change anything that alters the question. Editing for a better readability is an important part of the way [so] works.

Comment: sorry for that I am new to stack overflow. I don't know how to add those changes to my question. I saw your changes but I did not know how to apply that

Comment: I see. If a user is trusted enough (reputation >= 2000), edits are applied immediately. There is no action you have to take in that case (but you can still opt to roll back the changes, as you did). If a user has a lower reputation, the edit has to be reviewed and approved by other users.

Comment: Please see [How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Comment: thank you. I not getting this right  its mean if a user edited my question it auto-updated if a user has more than 2000 reputation.is that the case

Comment: Yeah, that is basically correct. The link also gives a rationale for why editing is allowed and viewed favourably: *"All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems as if your `add` method does not actually add anything. In your viewmodel you'll need to have a public property `YourList`, which is propagated with `add`. Furthermore you are getting only one item from your expenses database, which won't work for adding 10 items.

The core question as far as I understood is

> How can I add the 10 last items from an SQLite database to a Xamarin.Forms `ListView` using an MVVM approach.

Disregarding the fact that I do not know how and when you are calling `add`, I'll try to give an answer on how to get and add these elements.

First of all we need a property that will hold your items in your viewmodel. Depending on your requirements, either an `IEnumerable<AddExpenses>` or an `ObservableCollection<AddExpenses>` will do. I will demonstrate the `ObservableCollection` approach

```
ObservableCollection<AddExpenses> _expenses;

public ObservableCollection<AddExpenses> Expenses
{
    get
    {
        if(_expenses == null)
        {
            _expenses = new ObserrvableCollection<AddExpenses>();
        }
        return _expenses;
    }
}
```

You can bind to that property from your XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Expenses}" 
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<!-- What ever -->
</ListView>
```

And then add items to that collection from your `AddExpenses` method (I felt free to give it a more meaningful name):

```
private void AddExpenses()
{
    var database = new Database();
    var expenses = database.GetLastExpenses(numberOfExpenses: 10);

    foreach(var expense in expenses)
    {
        Expenses.Add(expense);
    }
}
```

Since we are now having objects of type `AddExpenses` in your collection, we'll have to change the binding in the `ListView` from `Categoryview` to `Category`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}" 
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Expense}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Last but not least we'll have to implement `GetLastExpenses` (this should work, while it's possible that there are better options)

```
public AddExpenses[] GetLastExpenses(int numberOfExpenses)
{
    return Conn.Table<AddExpenses>()
               .OrderByDescending(expenses => expenses.Date) 
               .Take(numberOfExpenses)
               .OrderBy(expenses => expenses.Date) // If you need them ordered ascending
               .ToArray()

}
```